# Bash script read file:argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My code

```
#!/bin/bash

file =$( < 262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat)

awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' file > output
```

Terminal

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/procmt$ bash a5.sh
a5.sh: line 3: /usr/bin/file: Argument list too long
```

Why?

Comment: You can just use: `awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' 262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat > output` no need of `$(<..)` and it has a syntax error as well (space before `=`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace matters.

This is not an assignment -- instead, it's running the command named `file` with an argument list that starts with an `=` and consists of the contents of the file `262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat` string-split and glob-expanded (which happen to be too long to put on an argument list):

```
# runs the file command with an argument list based on the contents of your .dat file
# will thus fail if the .dat file's contents cannot fit on a UNIX command line
file =$( < 262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat)
```

**This** is an assignment:

```
# reads the contents of your .dat file into the variable named file
# note that this doesn't correctly handle content with NUL literals
file=$(<262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat)
```

...and you could feed the contents you read into the input of `awk` as such:

```
# feed contents of the file variable on stdin to awk
awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' <<<"$file" > output
```

---

That said, it's not clear why you're trying to assign the file's contents to a variable at all. Why not just connect `awk` straight to the file?

```
# store filename in a variable
file=262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat

# ...and pass that filename to awk
awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .03 }' "$file" > output
```